# How would I calculate the standardized value of y given the standardized value of x and

Tags: correlation, prediction, standard-deviation, standardization

If the correlation between two variables, $x$ and $y$, is $-1/2$, and the standardized value of $x$ is $-4$, how would I predict the standardized value of $y$ with just those two pieces of information?

To figure out the standardized value of $y$, wouldn't I also need to know the standard deviation of $y$ ($s_y$) and the average of $y$ ($\bar{y})$?

$z = \frac{y_i - \bar{y}}{s_y}$

Comment: You'd actually need to know something about their joint distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b so is this problem unsolvable then?

Comment: There's nothing about assuming normality anywhere? If not, I think the best you can do is try to find bounds one the answer.

Comment: \* ...er *bounds on* the answer

Comment: @Glen_b I believe this question *is* answerable with extremely weak assumptions: namely, any assumptions that would justify an OLS linear regression of $x$ and $y.$ It is probing to see whether the respondent understands the relationship between the standardized OLS coefficient and the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps that's the case, though that suggests some context/conditions have been omitted in what's posted here.